# how to check if my app is downloadable from google play

Tags: android, google-play, download

I uploaded an app I developed to google play. Since the app isn't free, google doesn't allow me to download it to my device.
The first users who tried to download my app claimed they got the 505 error (by leaving their comments on google play).
I read some threads about this error here on stackoverflow and made some changes that hopefully fix the problem, but how can I check it myself? Do I need to use other people's devices and pay each time I want to check if my app is downloadable or is there a better option ?
thanks

edit: just to be clear -  I'm looking for a way to see whether people can download and install my app without getting any error messages. Preferably by going to the google play and downloading it myself. 
The app itself works great once it's downloaded and installed. The problem was that people couldn't download/install it on their device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Administration to check erros and statistics for your apps.

Login to your Google Account on this page:

https://play.google.com/apps/publish

There you'll find all your uploaded apps. You'll also find crash reports, etc. Just for better administration of your apps.

To test your app the best way is to use the debug or Run 'app' option in Android Studio. If you want to test the signed apk you can also build it inside Android Stuido with the Build -> Generate Signed APK option.
Or you use the console commands if you don't use an IDE.
Check the documentation of the ADB (Android Debug Bridge)

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering.
The "crashes and ANR's" says "no crashes found".
I'm not looking to test my app. I'm looking for a way to see if it can be downloaded from the google play.

Comment: Ah i got it, sorry my mistake, i thought the user gets the error during the usage of your app.

If the app is in the store you can actually install it. If there are no crashreports, nothing should be wrong with your app. Maybe the user uses an old browser. 505 stands for HTTP Not Support. It happens if you want to use a http request on a https site

To be sure you can generate a signed apk as mentioned above. Install it manually on your device, if everything works your app is just fine.

Comment: When I install it manually, all is well. I can't download it from the store cause they have a policy in google that the developer of an app can't download their own app if it's not a free app. More than 1 users left messages that they can't download my app and I see more failed attempts in the google console.

Comment: Do you see any working installations?  You can check it under the all apps view in google administration.
https://play.google.com/apps/publish
You can also see how many people have the app installed.

If there are no entries you have to contact the google support.

Comment: 0 people have it installed.

Comment: So best way is to contact the support. Please inform me what was wrong.